# Why does this input shape Not match the Keras model and my data?

Tags: keras, valueerror

I am struggling to see why Keras can Not load my data into a simple Sequential model.
All I want to do is load the data that looks like this:

So I have 8295 samples, each sample is made up of 400 data points and within that, 76 points.
The output is one of 3 categories.

I tried this and it fails and I have tried variations but nothing works.
`model = Sequential(name='MLP_Sequential') model.add(Dense(400, input_shape=(400,76), activation='relu')) model.add(Dense(76, activation='relu')) model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))`

For which I get the error:
`ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 400, 3) are incompatible`

I read several articles on "input shape" but I don't get it at all !!!, nothing works whatever I try.

I want to build a simple NN but its proving impossible.

Please can someone assist in the model definition that can load this data ?
Thanks.